# How to print elements from generic array list, using iterator in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator

I'm working in a school project, where I want to implement the Iterator design pattern. I want to use generic arrays.

Container.java

```
public interface Container {
     Iterator getIterator();
}
```

Iterator.java

```
public interface Iterator <T> {
     boolean hasNext();
     T next();
}
```

TransactionRepository.java

```
public class TransactionRepository<T> implements Container {
    public TransactionRepository(){
        userTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public List<T> userTransactions;

    @Override
    public Iterator <T> getIterator() {
        return new UserTransactions();
    }

    private T t;

    public void add(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    private class UserTransactions implements Iterator <T> {

        int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < userTransactions.size();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(this.hasNext())
                return userTransactions.get(index);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In my other class, I add the elements to the list by first creating the TransactionRepository object like this: `TransactionRepository<String> companyName = new TransactionRepository<String>();`.
Then I add elements to the array with the add method `companyName.add("CompanyName");`. After that I want to print the array using Iterator, but It just won't print the elements. I have tried multiple variations, but none of them worked.

```
Iterator <String> stringIterator = companyName.getIterator();

        while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Name : " + companyName.get());
        }
```

Comment: By the way, Java has its own Iterator interface.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: I think the idea of that task was to create own implementation of iterator design pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With the current implementation `List<T> userTransactions` is never updated.

In this case `userTransactions.size()` in `hasNext()` method will always return `0` so the result of method will be `false`.

2. Moreover, you should use `stringIterator.next()` instead of `companyName.get()`. Since you implement your own iterator you don't want to use `get()` method at all.
3. There is also a need to update `index` counter variable after calling `next()` method.

   ```
   @Override
   public T next() {
       if (this.hasNext())
           return userTransactions.get(index++);
       return null;
   }
   ```
4. Change modifier on `userTransactions` to `private final` as it should be referenced just with iterator.

Code with proposed improvements:

```
public class TransactionRepository<T> implements Container {
    public TransactionRepository() {
        userTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<T> userTransactions;

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> getIterator() {
        return new UserTransactions();
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        userTransactions.add(t);
    }

    private class UserTransactions implements Iterator<T> {

        int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < userTransactions.size();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (this.hasNext()) {
                return userTransactions.get(index++);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this way it will give you an error , because it hasnt been initialized , you should make it at 0 first

Comment: @KaramMohamed `int` is initialized by default with value `0` :)

Comment: @KaramMohamed It will not. Just run the code, please :)

Comment: @Zsolti I have added point 4 as it is also important in such case

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are never adding elements to your userTransactions List on the add method

Comment: I have changed the add method to userTransactions.add(t);
Now if i try to print the elements It's a never ending loop, and the name is null.

Comment: it's because on this line return userTransactions.get(index); you are not increasing the index so it its allways returning the first value, also, you are trying to print companyName.get() and that get returns the value of t but you are not assigning the value of t in the next() method

Answer (score 1):

You `add()` method doesnt add anything to your list , it's just like a setter of the attribute t , you should use it to add elements to the list instead

```
public void add(T t) {
    userTransactions.add(t);
}
```

There is also another problem , the **index** , your next() method gets the index element while you didnt initialise your index variable , i recommand you to do it in this way :

```
int index = 0 ;
...
public T next() {
   if(this.hasNext())
          int temp = index;
          index++;
          return userTransactions.get(temp);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Something is still off, Now it's an infinite loop, and the name is always null.

Comment: @Zsolti i edited my answer to show you another problem that making you get null